# Redirect php page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My old domain address is http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?t=123456

and then I want to redirect all these type of addresses to http://www.newdomain.com/viewtopic.php?t=123456

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule viewtopic\.php?t=([^/]+)$ http://freeware2010.com/viewtopic.php?t=$1
```

The code does not appear to work.

Answer (score 1):

You want a permanent (301) redirect. Here are a couple of tutorials on how to do it (the first being very verbose and slow-paced, so good for a beginner).

http://www.gnc-web-creations.com/301-redirect.htm

http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/301-redirect-with-mod_rewrite-or-redirectmatch.html

Comment: Your answer to that other question was the first thing I though of. Particularly, "Google it for more. This gets asked a lot."

Comment: Yeah, especially tonight there are a lot of people asking it. This asker seemed to be unsure of what it's even called, hence that clarification.

Comment: I try this but it is not working..


RewriteRule viewtopic.php?t=(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/viewtopic.php?t=$1 [R=301,L]